# How to prevent laptop from going to sleep when SSH'ing to it?

Tags: 18.04, ssh, suspend

I have used `dconf` settings to prevent my laptop from going to sleep when the lid is closed. This seems to require that there's a user logged in so it's not a global setting (is there a global setting somewhere?).

However, when I log in via SSH the laptop soon goes to sleep. So somehow the SSH login overrides the GUI login.

Is there something I could do to prevent this?